# sed substring from incoming packet

Tags: regex, linux, sed

String I want to sed i get from incoming sniffered packet... I want to get substring from string, f.e.

```
INVITE sip:18455845013@192.168.192.253:5060 SIP/2.0
```

Using `sed` I would like to extract substring.
Substring is between `sip:` and `@` ... So for my example, I need to get

```
18455845013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input file

```
$ cat foo.txt
INVITE sip:18455845013@192.168.192.253:5060 SIP/2.0
```

Result

```sh
$ sed 'y/:@/\r\n/;P;d' foo.txt
18455845013
```

- change `:` to `\r`
- change `@` to `\n`
- print up to first newline
- delete pattern space

Comment: Oh, Steven thanks!!! I will accept your answer!!! By myself I have made by **grep -oE "sip\:[0-9]{1,11}"** ... Now will decide what to use!!! Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports the `-P` flag, try:

```
grep -oP '(?<=sip:)[^@]*'
```

Results:

```
18455845013
```

Else, use `sed` like Steven Penny has done. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the bit between the : and @.

```
sed 's/.*:\(.*\)@.*/\1/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "INVITE sip:18455845013@192.168.192.253:5060 SIP/2.0" | sed 's/.*:\(.*\)@.*/\1/'
18455845013
```